# Subtracting two columns then deleting the line where the output equals 0 using awk/grep and vi

Tags: awk, grep

I'm having problems formatting files. I want to subtract the values from column 2 and column 3 and where the result is 0, I want to delete the line and save the file to a separate output file.

Here is the input file:

```
chr9    139844640       139844640       18450
chr9    139888759       139888925       18451
chr9    139965116       139965298       18453
chr9    139981357       139981444       18454
```

Output file:

```
chr9    139888759       139888925       18451
chr9    139965116       139965298       18453
chr9    139981357       139981444       18454
```

At the minute I'm doing it the very long winded way:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { $4 = "diff." } NR >= 0 { $4 = $2 - $3 } 1' input.bed > input_B.bed
```

then running grep on the command line:

```
grep -wn 0 input_B.bed
```

and deleting the lines in vi.

Any suggestions for an easier/ quicker way would be brilliant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as:

```
awk '$2 - $3' infile >outfile
```

because [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) has a default action of printing. So, a result different of `0` (`true`) triggers it.

It yields:

```
chr9    139888759       139888925       18451
chr9    139965116       139965298       18453
chr9    139981357       139981444       18454
```